# What is the purpose of `nil` private methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Using ruby 2.3, and pry REPL, I have this funny result I cannot understand:

```
nil.private_methods
# [:DelegateClass, :Digest, :sprintf, :format, :Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :throw, :iterator?, :block_given?, :catch, :loop, :Rational, :trace_var, :untrace_var, :Complex, :at_exit, :gem_original_require, :URI, :set_trace_func, :select, :caller, :caller_locations, :test, :fork, :`, :exit, :sleep, :respond_to_missing?, :load, :exec, :exit!, :syscall, :open, :printf, :print, :putc, :puts, :readline, :readlines, :p, :abort, :gets, :system, :spawn, :proc, :lambda, :srand, :pp, :rand, :initialize_copy, :initialize_clone, :initialize_dup, :Pathname, :trap, :gem, :BigDecimal, :require, :require_relative, :autoload, :autoload?, :binding, :local_variables, :warn, :raise, :fail, :global_variables, :__method__, :__callee__, :__dir__, :eval, :method_missing, :singleton_method_added, :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined, :initialize]
```

It looks likes those private methods are linked to modules loaded:

```
methods = nil.private_methods.dup
require "json"
nil.private_methods - methods
# [:j, :JSON, :jj]
```

I'm wondering about the purpose of those private methods and didn't find anything relevant on the internet.

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: Yes, and I'm still looking. I didn't find anything yet, any hint would be welcomed!

Comment: @lurker A good documentation helps reader understand what is going on. Reading source code is not always fun. Also, a language should be something people can learn without any pre requisite.

Comment: @ArupRakshit looking at source is not "fun" always, but it is educational and should at least be given an examination when questions like this arise. This is a Ruby internals question which deserves a look at the source and is something that may not be explicitly documented. It's at least a starting point if nothing else. I didn't claim it would necessarily answer all the questions or even not raise new ones.

Comment: @lurker I don't agree with you. As per you, before learning Ruby, I first need to learn C. And before I learn C, I need to learn things on which C is written. What he asked is not related to Ruby internals. It is related how the inheritance and mixing works in Ruby.

Comment: @ArupRakshit that's a fanciful extrapolation of what I was suggesting. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NilClass` does not declare any private instance method on it’s own. They came from `Kernel` and `BasicObject`:

```
NilClass.ancestors
#⇒ [NilClass, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
NilClass.private_instance_methods -
  (NilClass.ancestors - [NilClass]).flat_map(&:private_instance_methods)
#⇒ []
```

Any ruby class is derived from `BasicObject` and includes `Kernel`.

Also, [`Module#private_instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private_instance_methods) accepts the boolean argument, which suppresses the output of inherited methods when set to `false`:

```
NilClass.private_instance_methods false
#⇒ []
```

`JSON` on the other hand monkey patches `NilClass` amongst all other classes:

```
require 'json'
NilClass.ancestors
#⇓ [NilClass, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::NilClass,
#   Object, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object,
#   PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: Oh nice! So for my second example, it is the inclusion in `Kernel` as public methods of `JSON`, `j` and `jj`, that made it a private method for `NilClass`? The question being, when did it become private?

Comment: @UlysseBN these are [module functions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) which are available as both, class methods and instance methods. Additionally, _"The instance-method versions are made private"_

Comment: `require` is a Kernel method. If you add to it, then you add to all, hence you only need to `require` a script once to make it accessible anywhere in the program.

Answer (score 3):

Here are `NilClass`'s private methods organized by owner. Notice that none of these methods are from `NilClass`, the module `JSON` or any nested module within `JSON`.

```
require 'json'

nil.private_methods.sort.group_by { |m| NilClass.method(m).owner }
  #=> {Kernel=>[:Array, :Complex, :Float, :Hash, :Integer, :JSON, :Rational,
  #             :String, :__callee__, :__dir__, :__method__, :`, :abort,
  #             :at_exit, :binding, :block_given?, :caller, :caller_locations,
  #             :catch, :eval, :exec, :exit, :exit!, :fail, :fork, :format,
  #             :gem, :gem_original_require, :gets, :global_variables,
  #             :initialize_dup, :iterator?, :j, :jj, :lambda, :load,
  #             :local_variables, :loop, :open, :p, :print, :printf, :proc,
  #             :putc, :puts, :raise, :rand, :readline, :readlines, :require,
  #             :require_relative, :respond_to_missing?, :select, :set_trace_func,
  #             :sleep, :spawn, :sprintf, :srand, :syscall, :system, :test,
  #             :throw, :trace_var, :trap, :untrace_var, :warn],
  #    Object=>[:DelegateClass, :default_src_encoding, :irb_binding],
  #    Module=>[:autoload, :autoload?, :initialize_clone, :initialize_copy],
  #    Class =>[:initialize], BasicObject=>[:method_missing, :singleton_method_added,
  #             :singleton_method_removed, :singleton_method_undefined]}
```

One could instead write

```
NilClass.private_instance_methods.sort.group_by { |m| NilClass.method(m).owner }
```

The second part of the question asks the purpose of each of these methods. I will take these in turn.

*`:Array`*

For example, `nil.send(:Array, 2) #=> [2]`. I'm not quite sure how this might be used.

*`:Complex`*

For example, `nil.send(:Complex, 2,3) #=> (2+3i)`.  I'm not quite sure how this might be used.

*`:Float`*

To be completed...

Comment: I don't see `foo` in my IRB. Probably you defined a method `foo` in IRB for testing something... _I'm not quite sure how this might be used._ -- annoying side effect of Inheritance :)

Comment: @Arup, I tracked down the two `foo` methods. I had defined them in my `.irbrc` file. I must have put them there for some testing and forgot to remove them.